# Change the spring boot admin registery unique ID

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, spring-boot-admin

I have a requirement where my client applications are having almost same properties and even the URL is same, as they are running behind a load balancer, the only change they have is a particular set of environment properties that differ.

Is it possible to register them uniquely based on that property.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there are a few approaches.

- One would be loading Environment Variables from a [Kubernetes Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).
- Second using `helm`(https://helm.sh/)

  > Helm helps you manage Kubernetes applications — Helm Charts help you define, install, and upgrade even the most complex Kubernetes application.
  >
  > Charts are easy to create, version, share, and publish — so start using Helm and stop the copy-and-paste.

Explanation:
If you would use a `secret` option, you would probably create two separate secrets with env variables that you need and load those based on the app name, or if you have them setup in different `namespaces` then copy the `secret` over to each as those resources will not work between different `namespaces`.

If you would use `helm`, you will have to write your chart and put the env variables into `values.yaml` or mix it together and load `secret` from inside Kubernetes.

This will work on [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), I do not know (based on your tags) if it's the same on [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/).

Please provide some samples of what you have already done and I'll provide more details.